# lift, jetty - redirect after login goes to wrong path

Tags: scala, jetty, lift

If I put my application in a subdirectory, e.g. by naming it cm.war, after a successful login the redirect goes to /cm/cm (should be /cm).

I don't believe I have done anything funny in the boot code,

```
val loggedIn =   If(() => User.loggedIn_?,  () => RedirectResponse(User.loginPageURL))
val loggedInSU = If(() => User.superUser_?, () => RedirectResponse(User.loginPageURL))
```

some menu code

```
, (Menu("Users") / "users" / "index" >> loggedInSU) submenus (userSubMenus)
```

later I am applying the User.sitemapMutator

Other redirects in the app works fine.

Stepping the code reveals that it indeed tries to redirect to / which gets transformed into /cm by the updateWithContextPath in the Req class. It could be that updateWithContextPath for some reason is called twice, but I have not been able to see that in the debugger.

It works well as long as I deploy the app as root.

I am using lift 2.4-M3 and have tried both jetty 7.4.5 and 6.1.24.

Does anyone have an idea of what's happening?

***edit***
Some more stepping reveals that the response actually looks alright, but it get's transformed in LiftServlet, fixHeaders, from /cm to /cm/cm.

Bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a known bug in 2.4-M3, see here: https://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/tickets/1082-redirectresponse-duplicates-contextpath